# ContentProvider: cursor object null when trying to acces data with ContentResolver

Tags: android

I'm trying to share some data between my apps using ContentProvider. I have a problem with accessing the data with resolver in the second app: Cursor object is null after query. Can't figure out where I made a mistake in the code so I'm asking  for help. Code of the first app which provides the data :

Provider in manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.piotr.planer">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".BroadcastEvent" />

    <provider
        android:authorities="com.example.piotr.planer.PlansProvider"
        android:name=".PlansProvider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:multiprocess="true" >
    </provider>

</application>
```

Provider class:

```
package com.example.piotr.planer;

public class PlansProvider extends ContentProvider {

// Unique namespace for provider
static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.piotr.planer.PlansProvider";

static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/cpplans";

static final Uri CONTENT_URL = Uri.parse(URL);

// Defining columns in database
static final String id = "id";
static final String name = "name";
static final String date = "date";

static final int uriCode = 1;

private static HashMap<String, String> values;

// UriMatcher matches our unique Uris with our ContentProviders
static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

// assigning these unique Uris
static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cpplans", uriCode);
}

// Defining database
private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myPlans";
static final String TABLE_NAME = "plans";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
        " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        " name TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        " date INTEGER);";


@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    // Creates Database
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    sqlDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if (sqlDB != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case uriCode:
            queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(values);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);

    }
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(sqlDB, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    return cursor;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case uriCode:
            return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/cpplans";
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI " + uri);

    }
}


@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long rowID = sqlDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    if (rowID > 0) {
        Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URL, rowID);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
        return uri;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Row insert failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int rowsDeleted = 0;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case uriCode:
            rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsDeleted;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int rowsUpdated = 0;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case uriCode:
            rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsUpdated;
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
        sqlDB.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqlDB);
    }
 }
}
```

The addPlanToProviderFunction() method:

```
private void addPlanToProvider(long timeInMillis, String eventName) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PlansProvider.name, eventName);
    values.put(PlansProvider.date, timeInMillis);

    Uri uri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(PlansProvider.CONTENT_URL, values);
}
```

The class in the second app where I want to get the data:

```
package com.example.piotr.zadaniowiec;

public class PlanList extends AppCompatActivity {

static final Uri CONTENT_URL = Uri.parse("content://com.example.piotr.planer.PlansProvider.cpplans");

ContentResolver resolver;
TextView planListTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_plans_list);

    planListTextView = findViewById(R.id.plan_list_text_view);
    resolver = getContentResolver();
    getPlans();
}

private void getPlans() {
    String[] projection = new String[]{"id", "name", "date"};
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(CONTENT_URL, projection, null, null, null); 

    String planList = "";
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {                         // I get an error here
        do {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
            planList = planList + id + name + date + "\n";
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    planListTextView.setText(planList);
 }
}
```

I get :

> "NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToNext()' on a null object reference."

Thanks anyone for the help.

Comment: Cursor is null in android 13 while its working fine till android 11. It seems there is some permission issue in latest android as provider of other app is not even called. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CONTENT_URL` is in the wrong format - you need a `/` after the authority, not a `.`

```
static final Uri CONTENT_URL =
    Uri.parse("content://com.example.piotr.planer.PlansProvider/cpplans");
```

As it is now, you're looking for the root path for a ContentProvider that has an authority of `com.example.piotr.planer.PlansProvider.cpplans`, which doesn't exist, hence the null Cursor.

Comment: What a stupid mistake. Now it works, thanks for the quick reply.